# Elasticsearch wildcard fails when there are numbers in search string

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have indexed some string in this index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
     "record" : {
           "properties" : {
               "my_suggest" : {
                   "type":"completion" 
                }
            }
      }
  }
}
```

In my index there are these values:

1. my_suggest = foo1
2. my_suggest = bar
3. my_suggest = something2

If I query:

```
   {
    "query":{
        "wildcard":{"my_suggest":"*foo*"}
        }
    }
```

I have returned the record number 1.

If I do this query:

```
   {
    "query":{
        "wildcard":{"my_suggest":"*foo1*"}
        }
    }
```

I have returned blank results. I am expecting the record number one.

Why this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch uses simple analyser by default, which removes any non letter characters.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-simple-analyzer.html

Please use another type of analyser or custom analyser as per your requirements.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-analyzers.html